# Kettle: load CSV file which contains multiple data tables

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to import data from a csv file which, unfortunately, contains multiple data tables. Actually, it's not really a pure csv file.

It contains a header field with some metadata and then the actual csv data parts are separated by:

```
//-------------

Table <table_nr>;;;;
```

An example file looks as follows:

```
Summary;;
Reporting Date;29/05/2013;12:36:18
Report Name;xyz
Reporting Period From;20/05/2013;00:00:00
Reporting Period To;26/05/2013;23:59:59


//-------------

Table 1;;;;
header1;header2;header3;header4;header5
string_aw;0;0;0;0
string_ax;1;1;1;0
string_ay;1;2;0;1
string_az;0;0;0;0
TOTAL;2;3;1;1


//-------------

Table 2;;;
header1;header2;header3;header4
string_bv;2;2;2
string_bw;3;2;3
string_bx;1;1;1
string_by;1;1;1
string_bz;0;0;0
```

What would be the best way to process load such data using kettle?

Is there a way to split this file into the header and csv data parts and then process each of them as separate inputs?

Thanks in advance for any hints and tips.

Best,
Haes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any steps that will really help you with data in such a format. You probably need to do some preprocessing before bringing your data into a CSV step. You could still do this in your job, though, by calling out to the shell and executing a command there first, like maybe an awk script to split up the file into its component files and then load those files via the normal Kettle pattern.